Limit what programs can call my anchor program via CPI
Is there a way I can write an anchor instruction to only allow it to be called via CPI by a certain set of predefined programs?

Maybe something with get_instruction_relative https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/limit-what-programs-can-call-my-anchor-program-via-cpi ?

I don't know if Anchor provides an easy way to do this, but you can require a "signature" by a PDA from one of the allowed programs. If a PDA is marked as a signer, then the instruction had to originally come from that program. The caller program just needs to "sign" with that PDA.
